# How to use getIdentifier() on a string array for strings from resources

Tags: android, arrays

I have a string in a database that is in the layout of the following:

```
String fromdatabase = "one,two,three,four";
```

Basically I want to get this to the following format for further processing and use:

```
String[] array = new String[]{R.string.one,R.string.two,R.string.three,R.string.four};
```

So far I have the following code that converts the string to a string array, but do not know how to go from there. I was thinking a for-loop with some form of

```
getResources().getIdentifier(???,"string","package"));
```

then putting it into a new string array at the end, but I do not know where to start with this.

```
String[] split_fromdatabase = fromdatabase.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of trial an error, this code seems to work. 
It may not be the best written, but it works:

```
String[] split_fromdatabase = dropped_by.split(",");
        a = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i1=0; i1 <Adropped_by.length; i1++){
            System.out.print(Adropped_by[i1]);
            int res = getResources().getIdentifier(split_fromdatabase [i1],"string",getPackageName());
            a.add(getString(res));
        }
        db = new Object[a.size()];
        db = a.toArray(db);
```

Answer (score -1):

R.string.one means you are pointing to a string in 'res' folder.

You can not create Strings(or anything) in res folder at runtime.

Comment: I'm not creating strings, I am just referencing them for later use in drawing views. Probably with some modification to the `getIdentifier` method as mentioned in my question, but for string arrays.

Comment: id recommend you to pass the string itself. or change your database or use Map etc

Comment: I would, but I have multiple languages to work with, so it would be easier to get strings from resource files.

Comment: i saw ur solution,  retrieving resources based on name is not efficient especially when you need them to display to the user(i assume its ur case).

Comment: I've done some testing since posting my answer, and it allows me to load my activity much faster than previously :)